# Stand alone AngularJS date picker that does not require huge framework

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

Would like to know what others are using as of 2015 for an Angular date picker that is an ***independent plugin.***

Note: I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24515056/what-is-the-recommended-date-picker-for-angular-bootstrap), which references [UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), but the requirement is for a stand alone library. So that rules out [Angular Strap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/) as well :(

**What I found so far:**

http://720kb.github.io/angular-datepicker/
The 720k angular-datepicker looks promising, says it is responsive, and is recently maintained.  IE compatibility is a question mark on its github page though, which would be nice.

https://github.com/alongubkin/angular-datepicker Port of pickdate.js to Angular, with jQuery stripped out. Interesting that it is 'responsive', but I wonder how well the bugs are worked out.

https://github.com/g00fy-/angular-datepicker Pretty full featured, but lacks docs.

Answer (score 3):

After having a few issues with angular-strap I implemented the following:
https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday

Worked well!

Answer (score 1):

http://myplanet.github.io/angular-date-picker/

- Localizable
- Pure CSS – does not use any images
- Pure Angular – does not rely on any other libraries
- Compatible with IE8+